# How can I get the intersection point of two crossing ecdfs in R?

Tags: r, intersection, cdf, ecdf

I have two ecdf plots using below code:

```
ecdf1 <- ecdf(data1)
ecdf2 <- ecdf(data2)
```

These plots are crossing each other. I need to take the crossing point (intersection point) coordinates. How should I do this in R?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets' create a reproducible example to demonstrate:

```r
set.seed(1)

data1 <- rnorm(50) + 1.2
data2 <- rexp(50)
```

Now we use your code to create the two ecdf functions:

```r
ecdf1 <- ecdf(data1)
ecdf2 <- ecdf(data2)
```

If we plot them, we will see these curves intersect at two points: once between 0 and 1, and again just above 2.

```r
plot(ecdf1, col = "red")
plot(ecdf2, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

To find these exact points, we create a function of x that is the difference between the two ecdf functions at x. We then use the function `uniroot` to determine where this difference function is equal to 0:

```r
diff_func <- function(x) ecdf1(x) - ecdf2(x)

root1 <- uniroot(diff_func, c(0, 1))$root # Finds the lower intersection
root2 <- uniroot(diff_func, c(2, 3))$root # Finds the upper intersection
```

We can check our results make sense:

```
root1
#> [1] 0.1568627
root2
#> [1] 2.055556
```

And even plot segments to demonstrate the intersections are correct:

```r
segments(root1, y0 = 0, y1 = ecdf1(root1), lty = 2)
segments(root2, y0 = 0, y1 = ecdf1(root2), lty = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. It completely works fine. If possible can you give me advice, on the case that I do not know in which interval the intersection happens, how can I use your approach?

Comment: No worries, I found my answer. Thanks a lot for your help